# Passing parameters start and end dates from a stored procedure to the main report and three subreports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 to pass parameters (startdate and enddate) to the main Crystal Report and three subreports.  Right now the report is asking four separate times for the start and end dates.  I only want to enter the start and end date once and pull all the information for all the reports.  Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Yes. You have to link your start and end dates properly between main and subreports. Hard for me to help without seeing what you have going on though

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 4 times because you haven't linked the parameters from main report to sub reports.

First create the parameters `startdate` and `enddate`, Now in each sub report create parameters with same name.

For each and every sub report `right click --> change sub report links` add the startdate and enddate and in the right side bottom of the box you will get the drop down to link the added parameters to sub report parameters, There select the already created parameters.

This way main report and sub report parameters are linked, Follow the same process for all sub reports.

Now when you run the report only once parameters are prompted